# flask post request and get request

Tags: flask, flask-restful, flask-restplus

Friends

I am using get request in flask and sending parameters in url only
https://127.0.0.1:34/CheckOn?parameter1=abc&parameter2=deq

accessing the parameters using
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('parameter1', type=str)

Now for post I want to  pass these parameters in the request url only and access it
using method other than reqparse.RequestParser()
http://127.0.0.1:123/messages?new123=1234

Need to access new123 with method other than RequestParser

Answer (score 0):

No matter if you're using either GET or POST methods, you can get your URL parameters through Flask's `request.args` dictionary.

In your case it would be something like:

```py
from flask import request

@app.route('/CheckOn')
def check_on():
    parameter1 = request.args.get('parameter1') # abc
    parameter2 = request.args.get('parameter2') # deq
```